# node-canvas import ES Modules ( Mixing Import and Require )

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-canvas

I have a Dev environment ( macOS ) where

`import { createCanvas, loadImage, Image } from "canvas";`

works fine, but in production ( AWS Linux ) the same import:

`import { createCanvas, loadImage, Image } from "./node_modules/canvas"`

( if i don't use an explicit path I get `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`),

but I do now get error:

`Directory import '/home/ec2-user/<app>/node_modules/canvas' is not supported resolving ES modules`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found a fix...

There's a createRequire in "module", the purpose being able to mix import & require in the same project.

So I changed my import as follows:

```
import { createCanvas, loadImage, Image } from "canvas";
```

becomes:

```
import { createRequire } from "module";

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const { createCanvas, loadImage, Image } = require('canvas');
```

And now it works just fine!